# Tips on debugging segmentation faults when no leaks are found

Tags: c, debugging, memory-management, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I wrote a C-based application that appears to run fine, except on very large datasets as input.

With large input, I get a segmentation fault at the end steps of the binary's functionality.

I ran the binary (with the test input) with `valgrind`:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes /foo/bar/baz inputDataset > outputAnalysis
```

This job normally takes a few hours, but with `valgrind` it took seven days.

Unfortunately, at this point, I don't know how to read the results I am getting from this run.

I get a lot of these warnings:

```
...
==4074== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)                                                                                                                  
==4074==    at 0x435900: ??? (in /foo/bar/baz)                                                                                   
==4074==    by 0x439CC5: ??? (in /foo/bar/baz)                                                                                   
==4074==    by 0x400BF2: ??? (in /foo/bar/baz)                                                                                   
==4074==    by 0x402086: ??? (in /foo/bar/baz)                                                                                   
==4074==    by 0x402A0F: ??? (in /foo/bar/baz)                                                                                   
==4074==    by 0x41684F: ??? (in /foo/bar/baz)                                                                                   
==4074==    by 0x4001B8: ??? (in /foo/bar/baz)                                                                                   
==4074==    by 0x7FEFFFF57: ???                                                                                                                                                      
==4074==  Uninitialised value was created                                                                                                                                            
==4074==    at 0x461D3A: ??? (in /foo/bar/baz)                                                                                   
==4074==    by 0x43F926: ??? (in /foo/bar/baz)                                                                                   
==4074==    by 0x416B9B: ??? (in /foo/bar/baz)                                                                                   
==4074==    by 0x416725: ??? (in /foo/bar/baz)                                                                                   
==4074==    by 0x4001B8: ??? (in /foo/bar/baz)                                                                                   
==4074==    by 0x7FEFFFF57: ???
...
```

There are no parts of code hinted at, no names of variables, etc. What can I do with this information?

At the end, I finally get the following error, but — as with smaller datasets that do not crash — `valgrind` finds no leaks:

```
...
==4074== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)                                                                                                              
==4074==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x7158E7F7                                                                                                                      
==4074==    at 0x7158E7F7: ???                                                                                                                                                       
==4074==    by 0x4020B8: ??? (in /foo/bar/baz)                                                                                   
==4074==    by 0x6322203A22656D6E: ???                                                                                                                                               
==4074==    by 0x306C675F6E557267: ???                                                                                                                                               
==4074==    by 0x202C22373232302F: ???                                                                                                                                               
==4074==    by 0x6D616E656C696621: ???                                                                                                                                               
==4074==    by 0x72686322203A2264: ???                                                                                                                                               
==4074==    by 0x3030306C675F6E54: ???                                                                                                                                               
==4074==    by 0x346469702E373231: ???                                                                                                                                               
==4074==    by 0x646469662E34372F: ???                                                                                                                                               
==4074==    by 0x722E64616568656B: ???                                                                                                                                               
==4074==    by 0x63656D6F6C756764: ???                                                                                                                                               
==4074==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack                                                                                                                        
==4074==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but                                                                                                                       
==4074==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the                                                                                                                         
==4074==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.                                                                                                                        
==4074==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 10485760.                                                                                                                  
==4074==                                                                                                                                                                             
==4074== HEAP SUMMARY:                                                                                                                                                               
==4074==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks                                                                                                                                     
==4074==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated                                                                                                                    
==4074==                                                                                                                                                                             
==4074== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible                                                                                                                         
==4074==                                                                                                                                                                             
==4074== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v                                                                                                                
==4074== ERROR SUMMARY: 1603141870 errors from 86 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault
```

Everything I allocate space for gets an equivalent `free` statement, after which I set pointers to `NULL`.

At this point, how can I best debug this application, to determine what else is causing the segmentation fault?

---

**22 Dec 2011 - Edit**

I compiled a debug-version of my binary, called `debug-binary`, using the following compilation flags:

```
-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DUSE_ZLIB -g -O0 -Wformat -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99
```

When I run it with `valgrind`, I don't get much more information:

```
valgrind -v --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --error-limit=no --track-origins=yes debug-binary input > output
```

Here's a snippet of output:

```
==25116== 2 errors in context 14 of 14:                                                                                                                                                                                                      
==25116== Invalid read of size 4                                                                                                                                                                                                             
==25116==    at 0x4045E8: ??? (in /foo/bar/debug-binary)                                                                                                                                 
==25116==    by 0x40682F: ??? (in /foo/bar/debug-binary)                                                                                                                                 
==25116==    by 0x404F0C: ??? (in /foo/bar/debug-binary)                                                                                                                                 
==25116==    by 0x401FA4: ??? (in /foo/bar/debug-binary)                                                                                                                                 
==25116==    by 0x402016: ??? (in /foo/bar/debug-binary)                                                                                                                                 
==25116==    by 0x403B27: ??? (in /foo/bar/debug-binary)                                                                                                                                 
==25116==    by 0x40295E: ??? (in /foo/bar/debug-binary)                                                                                                                                 
==25116==    by 0x31A021D993: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.5.so)                                                                                                                                                                           
==25116==  Address 0x539f188 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 48 free'd                                                                                                                                                                    
==25116==    at 0x4A05D21: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:325)                                                                                                                                                                                    
==25116==    by 0x401F6B: ??? (in /foo/bar/debug-binary)                                                                                                                                 
==25116==    by 0x402016: ??? (in /foo/bar/debug-binary)                                                                                                                                 
==25116==    by 0x403B27: ??? (in /foo/bar/debug-binary)                                                                                                                                 
==25116==    by 0x40295E: ??? (in /foo/bar/debug-binary)                                                                                                                                 
==25116==    by 0x31A021D993: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.5.so)
```

Is this an issue with my binary, or with a system library (`libc`) that my application is dependent upon?

I also don't know what to do about interpreting the `???` entries. Is there another compilation flag I need to get `valgrind` to provide more information?

Comment: Have you run under GDB?  Are you building with debug information (`-ggdb` etc.)?  Are you putting any large data structures/arrays on the stack, or do you have any deep recursion?  (Basically, could you be overflowing the stack)?  Note also that Valgrind doesn't track buffer overflow on stack-allocated variables.

Comment: If you're sure that everything gets `free`d then you've buffer overrun issues somewhere

Comment: ... Or he keeps the stale pointer hanging around after freeing.

Comment: I have edited this question with results from compilation flag changes and a subsequent valgrind run.

Comment: alex - what ever happened with this? Just curious- having a very similar problem.

Answer (score 6):

Valgrind basically says there are no notable heap management issues.  The program is segfaulting from a less complex programming fault.

If it were me, I would

- compile it with `gcc -g`,
- enable core dump files (`ulimit -c unlimited`),
- run the program normally,
- and let it fault
- use `gdb` to examine the core file and look at what it was doing when it faulted:

> gdb (programfile) (corefile)
>      bt

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you point me to a well-documented approach to using gdb to examine core files?

Comment: @AlexReynolds:  I added the most typical commands to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe valgrind is able to find all errors where you've overrun a value on the stack (but not overrun the stack itself). So, you may want to try gcc's `-f-stack-protector-all` option.

You should also try mudflap, with `-fmudflap` (single-threaded) or `-fmudflapth` (multi-threaded).

Both mudflap and stack protector should be *much* faster than valgrind.

In additional, it looks like you don't have debug symbols, making reading backtraces difficult. Add `-ggdb`. 
You probably also want to enable core-file generation (try `ulimit -c unlimited`). This way, you can try to debug the process post-crash by using `gdb program core`.

As @wallyk indicates, your segfault may actually be something fairly easy to find—e.g., maybe you're dereferencing NULL, and gdb can point you to the exact line (or, well, close unless you compile with `-O0`). This would make sense, for example, if you're just running of memory for your larger datasets, and thus malloc returns NULL, and you forgot to check that somewhere.

Lastly, if nothing else makes sense, there is always the possibility of hardware issues. But those would be expected to be fairly random, e.g., different values getting corrupted different runs. If you try a different machine, and it happens there, its extremely unlikely to be a hardware issue.

Answer (score 2):

The *"Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value"* is a serious bug you need to fix.  It indicates that the behaviour of your program is affected by the contents of an uninitialised variable (including an uninitialised memory region returned by `malloc()`).

To get readable backtraces from valgrind you need to compile with `-g`.